# Java functional map() with threading

Tags: java, multithreading, functional-programming

I have an array of many hundreds of thousands of elements and I need to run a time consuming operation on each.  I'm hesitant to use Executor due to the shear number of elements, is there any way I can do the computation on all the elements utilising multithreading without rolling my own solution?

Comment: A `ForkJoinPool` with tasks for sub ranges of the array.

Comment: With Java 8, it can be as simple: `Arrays.stream(yourArray).parallel().forEach(/* your time consuming operation here*/);`, otherwise an Executor may or may be the solution depending on what operation you are doing...

Comment: What's wrong with an Executor?  The overhead of creating Callables/Runnables should be low.  You could bin your results if you're really concerned about it.